# ListView.setAdapter called twice on Samsung Galaxy S2 not updating correctly

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

Initially in my fragment I call

```
listView.setAdapter(myAdapater);
```

This adapter has a list with 0 elements, when this happens a single row is inserted that takes up the entire list (shows a loading image). After an api request gets the data, the adapter is updated and

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

is called. This works fine on all phones except the Samsung Galaxy S2, the loading row is still present as the first row in the list, and when you start to scroll you'll see the expected 2nd row come into view. If you scroll the first row off the screen then back on the screen this replaces the loading row with the correct row.

---

Second attempt -

Instead of handling it this way I created a second adapter,

```
public class LoadingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {}
```

Then when the fragment starts:

```
listView.setAdapter(loadingAdapter);
```

after the api request.

```
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

At this point the list is completely blank, but should render a list, just the background is shown. I played with this and doing

```
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

causes the same issue of the background just being shown.

Open to any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a view recycling issue.

Comment: I have print statements in `getView` for the adapter (myAdapter in this case). On other devices `getView` is called, when `notifyDataSetChanged` is called, but not called on the S2. Never even tries to load the view to recycle. =/

Answer (score 0):

> This adapter has a list with 0 elements, when this happens a single row is inserted that takes up the entire list (shows a loading image)

This is not the best way to show a view specifically when the adapter is empty. Instead, you should use ListView's [setEmptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)) method to set a specific view to be shown instead of the ListView when the adapter is empty. Generally, this should be a view at the same level as the ListView (i.e., use a FrameLayout that contains both the ListView and your empty view).

Comment: Agreed, we had initially set this up but then we implemented
[Pull to Refresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) prior to the release of the android v4 support library SwipeRefreshLayout. We're using that support library now but haven't swapped back to using the empty view. 
Either way, this wouldn't do anything for helping the issue with swapping adapters. Thanks for the response though.